# Javascript validation vs. business rules

Tags: jakarta-ee

I had a concept that I wanted to get clarity on, or find out if there is a best practice for. I have business logic in place(server side) for my web application for creating an account. The code validates to see if a first name and last name have been provided, and if so, does the database entry, and returns the account number.

On the web side, I have javascript validation that does that same type of validation on the fields before submitting to the servlet(making sure a first name, and last name have been provided before the servlet POST is even done).

My question is, is it common practice to have the business rule validation mirrored on the web/ui side in the form of javascript validations, or is there a more common practice? Another example may be that a first name has to be more than 1 character (made this rule up). The business logic is checking this before it makes the call to the database. Should I have this rule duplicated in my javascript? Is there a common practice for this, or does the approach to have some of the validation duplicated seem logical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider it good practice to do checking in both places because if you don't have any checking on the front-end (Javascript side of things), the user will have to submit the request, and possibly leave that page before discovering that the values she entered are invalid. Having it in-place allows them instant feedback that these values are invalid; this makes for a better user experience, IMHO.

Also, crafty users could use something like Poster or their own scripts to bypass the front-end validation, so you certainly want it on the backend as well. One thing you need to be careful with is making sure the two validations remain consistent. For example, if you decide that the first name could be omitted, but only change the validation on the front-end, the backend will prevent this newly-valid value from being submitted. I would recommend writing unit tests for both the front and back ends to maintain consistency.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is that the system entry should have the validation to make sure consistency is maintained. So, in your scenario the entry of your system is the web application back-end. So you need to have the validation on that side. 
Let me give you an example, let's say I create an automation tools that posts data to your web application and no UI is involved then, still if the tool does not provide the firstName, it should fail to record data.

This is much more obvious when your system is divided into a service layer and a web application (as the dumb UI) just to collect users input.

Now you still need to (or at least it is better too) put ui validation for firstName. The reason is not to really prevent users from leaving the field empty in terms of data consistency, because service layer does not let users anyway. But it is more for a better user experience (UX) so the users get a faster feedback.

In conclusion, yes, you should. But for different reasons.